# Function from natural to lexicographically ordered words of a-z

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inverse-function, regular-language, finitely-generated, regular-expressions

I think I am looking for a very basic lexicographic ordering concept/function/algorithm, but I'm stumped. Basically, it has to produce the following mapping:

```
f(0) = a
f(1) = b
...
f(25) = z
f(26) = aa
f(27) = ab
...
f(??) = zz
f(??) = aaa
```

I think what makes this difficult is that `a` != `aa`, in the sense that the symbol `a` is 0 when it is alone, but when going higher it is not anymore. For example, 26 is 10 in base 26. To contrast, the function I am looking for would return "aa" in that case. So it kind of assigns `a` to 1 if it is in the most significant position, and `a` to 0 if it's in a less significant position, if that makes sense... I guess I got to this reasoning by trying to implement `f` as a conversion into base26, but that doesn't work out, since it starts skipping `a`'s then (because, why would you write 00001, in that case you leave out the zeroes. Also, so when you get to `z`, and increment it, it increments to `ab`, and skips `aa`, because `z` = `za` in base26).

So I guess, to rephrase, I am looking for a bijection with type $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{a, \cdots,z\}+$, i.e., from the naturals to all words formed of symbols a to z. Is there such a function, and maybe even an efficient/simple implementation? It would also be great to have the inverse of that function, if it exists.

Comment: I think one way to figure out what $n$ maps to is to first figure out the largest $k$ such that $n\ge M=\sum_{i=1}^{k} 26^i$. Then represent $n-M$ in base 26, but with letters ($k+1$ of them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we well find $f^{-1} (word) $ and then using that to find $f(num)$,note that $f^{-1}(aa)=26$ because $aa$ comes after all the one letter words and there are $26$ start counting from $0$ because $f(a)=0$ then we get that $f^{-1}(aa)=26$ and $ f^{-1} (aaa)  = 702$ because it comes after all the one and two letter words and the two letter words are $26^2$ in total and start counting from $0$ we get that $f^{-1}(aaa)  = 702$ and in general $f^{-1} (a^M  = a\cdots a ) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{M-1} 26^i  = \frac{26^M-26}{25}$ and now we can generalize to any word simply be noticing that if we replace $m$ letters of $a$ with any other letter in any position we add $26^{pos} $ times $ value (letter)$ for instance $ f^{-1}(bc) = 26+ 1*26^1+2*26^0 = 54$ so the general formula is $ f^{-1}(word) =  \frac{26^M-26}{25}+ \sum \limits_{i=0}^{M} word[i]*26^i$  so for example $f^{-1}(a b c b a)= \frac{26^5-26}{25}+ 0*26^0+1*26^1+2*26^2+1*26^3+0*26^4 = 494,208$

Now for $f$ itself, if we only have this sum $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{M} word[i]*26^i $ it would be easy to figure out the word from it assuming we know $M$, so for any value $num$ we find the $M$ such that $ \frac{26^M-26}{25} \leq num < \frac{26^{M+1}-26}{25}$ (using $\log$ is one way $M= \lfloor \frac{\log(25num+26)}{\log{26}} \rfloor$) then we get the value $ num-\frac{26^M-26}{25} = \sum \limits_{i=0}^{M} word[i]*26^i$ and then using $\mod 26$ method to find the word, for example $f(10000)$ => $M = \lfloor 3.8149\rfloor = 3$ so we are looking for three letters word, $10000-\frac{26^3-26}{25}= 9298 $ , Now $ 9298 = 357*26+16$ and $ 357 = 13*26+19$ and $ 13 = 0*26+13$ and so the word in values is $\{13,19,16 \} = \{ n,t, q\}$ and so $f(10000)= ntq$.

In computer algorithm all the above is easily implemented (except maybe how to find $M$ quickly since the approach i took will not work in a pc because of the floating point problem, i hope someone will give better way to find $M$).

Comment: Depending on how large the $n$ may be, I would write a while loop in the function, starting at $M=0$, and ```while( 25n+26 >= 26^(M+1) ) M++```. Or you could use the floor like you suggested, and use that $M$ for the initial value.

Comment: Thank you! With your clear explanation I understood how to best solve this and was able to implement a solution in rust. In case anyone needs it: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8ff6572fa611204c95ed37914a4b7884), [gist](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/8ff6572fa611204c95ed37914a4b7884)

Comment: good coding, but be aware of the floating point problem for large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach. We consider
\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{base }\ 10\quad\to\quad \{0,1,\ldots,9\}\\
&\mathrm{base }\ \ \;2\quad\to\quad \{0,1\}\\
&\mathrm{base }\ 26\quad\to\quad \{\mathrm{a},\mathrm{b},\ldots,\mathrm{z}\}\qquad \mathrm{???}\\
\end{align*}
Regrettably taking base $26$ is not really promising cause we would have a mapping
\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{a}\ \quad \ \to 0\\
&\mathrm{b}\ \quad \ \to 1\\
&\quad\vdots\\
&\mathrm{z}\ \quad \ \to 25\\
&\mathrm{aa}\quad\to 0\cdot 26+0=0
\end{align*}
which gives us leading zeros which are not wanted.

> But we can overcome this drawback by introducing a **dummy symbol** $0$ and working with base $27$ instead of base $26$. This way we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{base }\ 27\quad\to\quad \{0,\mathrm{a},\mathrm{b},\ldots,\mathrm{z}\}}
> \end{align*}
> We now have the mapping
> \begin{align*}
> &\mathrm{a}\ \ \quad \to 1_{10}\\
> &\mathrm{b}\ \ \quad \to 2_{10}\\
> &\quad\vdots\\
> &\mathrm{z}\ \ \ \quad \to 26_{10}\\
> &\mathrm{aa}\ \quad \to 1\cdot 27 + 1 = 28_{10}\\
> &\mathrm{ab}\ \quad \to 1\cdot 27 +2 = 29_{10}\\
> &\quad\vdots\\
> &\mathrm{zz}\ \ \quad \to 26 \cdot 27 + 26 = 728_{10}\\
> &\mathrm{aaa}\quad \to 1\cdot 27^2+1\cdot 27^1+1 = 757_{10}
> \end{align*}

*Notes:*

- The mapping has some gaps, since we do not obtain base $27$ numbers which contain zeros. So, this is an injective mapping, not a bijective one. But, if this is not a problem ...
- The algorithm looks rather simple. In base $10$ we have for instance
  \begin{align*}
   387 = \left(3\cdot 10+8\right)10+7
   \end{align*}
  and similarly we have in base $28$
  \begin{align*}
   \mathrm{eac} \to \left(5\cdot 27 + 1\right)27 + 3 = 3\,675_{10}
   \end{align*}